# In Shin Megami Tensei IV, what does it mean when my character smirks?

Tags: smt4

I've noticed my character will often "smirk" in battle. What does this effect do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [This post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672441-shin-megami-tensei-iv/66770515) in Gamefaqs for a full discussion about it. Transcribing the important part here, Smirk does the following:

- Normal attacks have a 95% chance of being a critical hit.
- Gun attacks have a 70% chance of being a critical hit.
- Attack power increases. Effect is equivalent to three uses of Tarukaja. However, does not stack with support effects.
- Normal attacks, gun attacks, and attack skills all have a 100% hit rate. Does not apply to Hama, Muda, or ailment spells.
- Even if an enemy hits your weak point, it will be treated as a normal hit and not a weak point hit.
- Cannot receive critical hits.
- 85% chance to avoid all attacks. However, chance of succumbing to ailments does not change.
- If you have a full, four member party, getting all four to Smirk will heal everybody for 50% of their maximum HP and MP.